# How to select art-8, but not cart-8 with javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following if statement in javascript. I am targeting pages which have art-8 in url.

Sample url is like this,

http://www.mywebsite.com/art-8.asp?id=435&iPageID=43

However this will pick up an url with cart-8 and I don't want that.

I want only select art-8 in url not cart-8.

How should I change it?

```
if (location.pathname.indexOf('art-8') > 0){

...............
```

Do I need regex?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (/\/art-8\/?$/.test(location.pathname)) {
    ...
}
```

will match any pathname ending in `/art-8` or `/art-8/`. Or splitting the pathname into its component parts:

```
var parts = location.pathname.split('/').slice(1);
if(parts[parts.length - 1] == '') parts = parts.slice(0, -1);
if(parts[parts.length - 1] == 'art-8') {
    ...
}
```

**EDIT:** If `art-8` need not be at the end, but there is a slash before it:

```
if (/\/art-8/.test(location.pathname)) {
    ...
}
```

Or if there isn't necessarily a slash before it, but you just want to look for `art-8` without a `c` before it (pathname will always begin with a slash, so there will always be at least one character before and this will work):

```
if (/[^c]art-8/.test(location.pathname)) {
    ...
}
```

Note that pathname does not include the `?` and what comes after it, so even the first two examples I gave should work for the specific example URL you gave if you add `.asp` just after the `8`.

Comment: art-8 is a part of url, not at the end

Comment: @shin: Yes, it is a method of RegExp objects that returns `true` if the regex matches the given string and `false` if it does not. Both `/test/` and `new RegExp("test")` are ways to write regexes in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

What about this regexp?

```
[^c]art-8
```

Comment: What if the string is just `"art-8"`?

Comment: The pathname part is always going to begin with a slash, at least for HTTP.

Answer (score 0):

If you're only concerned with individual path segments, and you want to find only paths that contain at least one path segment that is exactly equal to 'art-8', then you could do this:

```
if (location.pathname.indexOf('/art-8/') > 0) {
```

which would work for all cases *except* the case where 'art-8' was at the end, without a trailing slash.  You could add another check for the special case, without the trailing slash, and including a check to be sure the index places it at the end of the line.

but if you're on modern browsers, with RegExp support, then all you need is:

```
var rx=new RegExp("/art-8(/|$)");
if( rx.test(location.pathname) ) {
  ...
}
```

w3schools has a [fairly comprehensive reference](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp) for the javascript RegExp object

Answer (score 0):

The regex way would be to use word boundary anchors:

`/\bart-8\b/` will only match `art-8`, not `cart-8` or `art-80`.

`\b` matches between word- and non-word-characters (or start/end of string), where word-characters are defined (in JavaScript) as `[A-Za-z0-9_]`.

The advantage of this approach is that it will also work if there are no characters surrounding the string you're looking for.